# Recommender system: simple user-based collaborative filtering to evaluate with precision and recall

Tags: java, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, precision-recall

I'm looking for a very simple implementation in Java of a user-based [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering). I would like to evaluate the precision and recall of this CF with the movielens dataset. I've seen that the performance (F1) should be around 20 to 30% (with Pearson similarity, and KNN).

Does this simple framework exist with the evaluation for precision and recall code?

Answer (score 8):

[Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org) does everything you mention here. It is Java-based, and supports user-based collaborative filtering (among others) with `GenericUserBasedRecommender`. It is a k-nearest-neighbor algorithm, into which you can plug similarity implementations like `PearsonCorrelationSimilarity` and others.

Look at the `org.apache.mahout.cf.taste` package and subpackages. In the `.impl.eval` subpackage find `GenericRecommenderIRStatsEvaluator`. This will run a test that reports precision, recall and F1.

Finally, there are already some working examples based on `GroupLens` in `mahout-examples`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However Apache Mahout is just impossible to use and requires too many packages. In addition, the lack of simple documentation (for instance, how to make a new project in eclipse in order to use Taste's classes) doesn't help...

Comment: Not sure what you mean? This piece of the code has just a few dependencies... SLF4J and Google Guava I believe. It is a Maven-based project, so you can just depend on it with a few lines in your Maven project if using Maven. You also have a simple .jar provided from the project with everything, which you can put into any Eclipse project like any other library. That's about it -- not much to document -- but if you are having specific problems I'm sure it's resolvable on user@mahout.apache.org.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried RapidMiner?
If you are interested in just try things like evaluate the precision and recall without concentrate on coding. That's the tool for you. There's good information on the web even paper and youtube videos tutorial like to help you.